# How to replace double quotes in a string?

Tags: vbscript

I need to replace `"`in a string with nothing.

I tried:

```
replace(mystring, """, "")
```

I would like:

```
String = " "my string " " --> " my string"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you are really wanting to do is replace any instance `"` with a blank string. To do this:

```
replace(mystring, chr(34), "")
```

`chr(34)` is the character code for a double quote. You could also use `replace(mystring, """", "")` that `""""` gets evaluated as one double-quote character, but I believe the `chr(34)` is much less confusing.

Comment: replace(mystring, chr(34), "") does not work for me with cscript on Windows 2012 R2. This did not produce an error from cscript. The script just terminated early. I could put in `stdout.WriteLine` just prior to this replace and it would write to the console, but the `stdout.WriteLine` immediately after this statement never wrote anything to the console. replace(mystring, """", "") is the only thing that ended up working.